# Get Integer portion of square root in Haskell

Tags: math, haskell, static-libraries, arbitrary-precision, square-root

Say I have a *large* integral number of the type `Integer`. Does there exist a library function (in Prelude or elsewhere) which, when given an `Integer` **X** will return the integral portion of the square root of **X** as an `Integer`?

Comment: I assume you've googled for integer square root?

Comment: @GregS Of course, I want to know if there are library solutions before rolling my own.

Comment: Is your integer unbounded or do you know of some practical and finite upper bound?

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson for practical purposes, unbounded.

Comment: In that case you must roll your own or use what you see on the Haskell wiki.  There is no access to the gnu gmp square root function from within GHC or hackage libraries.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson Then I guess I'm switching to **`C`**

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson Surely you can pull it in via FFI?

Comment: @chunksOf50 [It's harder than you might guess.](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.haskell.glasgow.user/6609)

Comment: @DanielWagner Ah. I see now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [arithmoi](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/arithmoi-0.4.0.3/docs/Math-NumberTheory-Powers-Squares.html) package has an `Integer` square root function called `integerSquareRoot` that works for any `Integral` instance.

It also has specialization rules so that you can use it on plain `Ints` and have the root computed via the sqrt function on Doubles.

Comment: I accepted your answer because I have used the `Math.NumberTheory` libraries before. [Daniels answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21493329/1465011) is no less correct, but I prefer yours.

Answer (score 7):

You can go via [`CReal`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/numbers-3000.2.0.0/docs/Data-Number-CReal.html).

```
isqrt :: Integer -> Integer
isqrt = floor . (sqrt :: CReal -> CReal) . fromInteger
```

Comment: Too bad `Data.Number.CReal` doesn't export [`floorsqrt`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/numbers-2009.8.9/docs/src/Data-Number-CReal.html#floorsqrt), but hopefully GHC will optimize away the superfluous conversions.

Comment: Thank **`$deity`**, I don't have to switch the project over to **`C`** because of this!

Comment: @rampion You're right, that *is* a shame! I seriously doubt GHC will do the optimization you're suggesting, though.